# Escaping unescaped forward slashes

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have strings which contain both escaped and unescaped forward slashes.

I'm looking for a sed substitution to escape **only the unescaped slashes**, but it seems like negative lookbehinds are not supported.

Example:

```
input: "https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https://baz/test.com"

desired output: "https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https:\/\/baz\/test.com"
```

Comment: Do you have to use `sed`?

Comment: Nope, anything is fine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` uses [POSIX basic regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) by default, which does not include lookahead and other zero-width assertions usually found in Perl-compatible regular expression languages.

Instead, simply unescape the escaped slashes, and then escape all slashes in the modified string:

```bash
sed -e 's@\\/@/@g' -e 's@/@\\/@g'
```

This first changes all instances of `\/` into `/`, and then all `/` into `\/`.  The `@` is an alternative delimiter for the substitution command to avoid [the leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) (you could use almost any other character).

Example:

```bash
$ echo '"https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https://baz/test.com"' | sed -e 's@\\/@/@g' -e 's@/@\\/@g'
"https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https:\/\/baz\/test.com"
```

---

If the line of text is stored in a string in the `bash` shell, you could do something similar there:

```bash
$ string='"https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https://baz/test.com"'
$ string=${string//\\\///}   # leaning toothpick warning!
$ string=${string//\//\\/}
$ printf '%s\n' "$string"
"https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https:\/\/baz\/test.com"
```

The above uses the `${variable//pattern/replacement}` variable substitution which replaces all matches of `pattern` in `$variable` with `replacement`.

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, so you can use lookbehinds:

```
$ input="https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https://baz/test.com"

$ printf '%s\n' "$input" | perl -pe 's|(?<!\\)/|\\/|g'
https:\/\/github.com\/foo\/bar\/pull\/2934) is live at https:\/\/baz\/test.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
sed 's:\\\?/:\\/:g'
```

Replace any slash with zero or one preceding backslash with an escaped slash.

Answer (score 0):

sed does not have lookbehind assertions, but we can emulate them. Shown here with GNU sed in extended regex mode (-E)

```
sed -E '
  :a
  s:(^|[^\])(([\][\])*)[/]:\1\2\\/:
  t a
' file
```

We make sure that to the left of / are an even number of backslashes(0 is even) before it sees a non backslash OR hits the beginning of line.